# Xamarin Bluetooth library

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to write a Xamarin Native (not Xamarin.Forms) solution for Android and iOS.

The application needs to find and communicate with a bluetooth device.

The device uses classic Bluetooth and not BLE.

Is there a good library for cross-platform (Core) or native that support API > 19? I only found libraries for Xamarin.Forms or BLE.

I tried the solution of creating a [BroadcastReceiver](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2018/12/16/how-to-detect-nearby-bluetooth-devices-with-net-and-xamarin-android/) but it seems to not work on some version of Android.

Comment: Do you want to find unpaired device in IOS? I'm worried that might not be possible , i've read several sources saying the device must be paired first in iOS settings first. After a device is paired, you can get a list of paired devices in the app.

Comment: I know it's possible with BLE, Android and iOS. Are you sure there is no way of doing the same in classic Bluetooth?

Comment: You can look into native and make bindings

Comment: Yes, It is not possible to find the unpaired device in IOS.